# Update data using SQL parameter in C# with class

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a question regarding on update using `SqlParameter` with class...

In my class `EditRecord`:

```
string strScript = "";
strScript = strScript + "UPDATE tbMemberInfo(FirstName,LastName,Age)";
strScript = strScript + "SET (FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, Age = @age)";
strScript = strScript + "WHERE id=@empID";

SqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new SqlCommand(strScript, Connection);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _members.Lastname));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _members.FirstName));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", _members.Age));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", _members.ID));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Call the class in my Form

```
Class.clsMemberInfo member = new Class.clsMemberInfo();

member.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
member.Lastname = txtLastName.Text;
member.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

clsMembers memberInfo = new clsMembers();

memberInfo.Members = member;
memberInfo.EditREcord(cnTestConnection);
MessageBox.Show("Success");
```

But the data is not updating

Comment: Your query seems off. You need a space after each string. So: `"UPDATE tbMemberInfo(FirstName,LastName,Age) "` Also, make sure you have opened a connection

Comment: Your sql maybe upset because between age) and set there is no space, same as there is no space between @age and where.

Comment: debug your code, get sql script string before execute it and then  run it on Sql Server. you will not be surprised, trust me.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response but no change at all still I cannot update the data.... :(

Comment: @JolanMoski have you tried my answer?

Comment: Are you trying to update or Insert your values ?

Comment: yes sir and i applied it to my script but still cannot update my data

Comment: @JolanMoski, if you "cannot update data" then there is probably an error occurring, which we need to know. Details are important!

Answer (score 1):

change sql statement as

```
string strScript = "UPDATE tbMemberInfo SET FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, Age = @age WHERE id=@empID";
```

update syntax is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

there is no column names given in () next to table name

**UPDATE**

in your code `_members.ID` is not set before you call the method

```
Class.clsMemberInfo member = new Class.clsMemberInfo();

member.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
member.Lastname = txtLastName.Text;
member.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
member.ID  = ??? //you need to give this value, otherwise your update will not work
```

Comment: Care to explain down votes! may be i'm wrong but there is clearly syntax issue with the OPs code

Comment: I have already edit my update sql but still cannot update my data

Comment: @JolanMoski, if you "cannot update data" then there is probably an error occurring, which we need to know. Details are important!

Comment: What additional detail you need to know Sir Peter B?

Comment: Your code worked Sir Poovizhi! Now how do i change the value of your sql statements? :)

Comment: you haven't given value for ID before calling the method